# Magento layout update not working on server

Tags: magento-1.7, template, layout-update

I'm facing a strange problem. I created a menu in admin backend. I wanted to display a form and submit it.

I created a module for that with controller and layout updates as well.

Now everything is working fine on my local server. I click the menu, a form opens, I submit it and everything is find.

Now when I upload this file on server (AWS Linux instance), my form (phtml) does not show. The layout is loaded but templates are not working. I checked carefully and all the files are uploaded properly.

I'm stuck at this for a long time now and do not know why is this not working on server while it is working fine on local system.

Please help me guys. If you want, I will post all my code here as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you clear the cache and check your log files if there's any hint? Additionally I would activate the dev mode on the server to see more possible errors.

Comment: Make sure the file owner and permissions are set correctly on the phtml file.

Comment: I updated the question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55056/my-admin-module-templates-are-not-loading-in-linux-but-works-fine-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment74097_55056

Answer (score 1):

Check so that the flag in System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable Modules Output for your modules is **not** set to disabled. That once cost me many hours of my life..

If it is enabled however, you probably have some information in the log files if logging is turned on and the var/ directory is writable.